# CANoe trace data in an excel file(.csv or.xlsx)

Tags: canoe

How to export CANoe trace data in an excel file(.csv or.xlsx) where we can see the messages and signals' names along with their updated values.

I tried storing the log file in .csv format but couldn't see the message and signal name details and their value. I hope there is someway to store the CANoe trace data in an excel file format which can be readable. Any suggestions? Any answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Logging/Export Block to save the entire measurement in a file as BLF or ASCII. Afterwards you convert the BLF into other formats like CSV or MAT. This can be found under Tools->Convert (I don't know the correct menu items in english, because I have only the german version of CANoe). If you convert an BLF file, you can select the time and the signals you want.

Another solution is to write an own exporter in CAPL and write directly into a file (I didn't try the code, it's just an idea).

```
on Start {
  glbHandle = OpenFileWrite ("Data.csv", 2);
}

on message * {
  int i;
  char buffer [64];

  write("[%07.3f] %03X,", this.time / 100000.0, this.id);
  for (i = 0; i < this.dlc; i++) {
    snprintf(buffer, elcount(buffer), "%02X, ", this.byte(i));
    filePutString(buffer, elcount(buffer), glbHandle);
}

on StopMeasurement {
  fileClose (glbHandle);
}
```